# How to configure schema.xml for geoSpatial Search in solr 7.6?

Tags: solr, geospatial

I am using Solr 7.6 for Searching and filtering. I want to filter data nearby location using Solr Spatial Search but can't find any data.

I have done the following changes in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true" />
<field name="latlong" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I've tried this query :

```
d=5&fq={!geofilt sfield=latlong}&pt=22.303894, 70.802162&q=*:*
```

my response :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "d":"5",
      "pt":"22.303894, 70.802162",
      "fq":"{!geofilt sfield=latlong}",
      "_":"1556533385742"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Expected Document:

```
{
        "zipCode":"360001",
        "currencySign":"₹",
        "suspendedByAdmin":false,
        "likeCount":62,
        "id":1372,
        "longitude":70.8023621,
        "countryname":"India",
        "statename":"Gujarat",
        "suspended":false,
        "city":"Rajkot",
        "latitude":22.2913494,
        "description":"Description is here"
        "_version_":1632151597023756288},
```

Comment: Have you seen [Spatial Search](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/spatial-search.html) and configured your field as a `LatLonPointSpatialField`?

Comment: yes, i tried but not working

Comment: So what does "not working" mean? Is the content present if you return the document? Are you using the correct syntax for geofilt? (`{!geofilt sfield=store}` - the `{!` and `}` parts are _important_). Does the schema browser show your field and the type you defined in `schema.xml`?

Comment: - Yes i'm using the correct syntax.
- yes schema browser shows my field and the type that defined in schema.xml.
- I have configured my field as a 'LatLonPointSpatialField', now does any more changes required?

Comment: Update your query to show the exact query you're using at least, show two example documents that you expect to be found (and remove the space after `,` in your source position).

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting point.

Comment: Your query, in the question, does not show the query you say you're executing - there's also a space after the first coordinate in your `pt` argument. To be able to further find out what the issue can be, at least one document that you expect to find with the query should be included. Also remember that any change to a field usually requires reindexing the data to make the change apparent.

Comment: I've  updated my question. let me know if need any more information.

Comment: You're still missing example documents that you expect to find.

Comment: @MatsLindh I've added expect a result.

Comment: Where is the location field for that document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution.
Firstly put the latlong value as text(lat,long) 
and then assign that latlong value as a location, this is use as sfield for geospatial query

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true" />
<field name="latlong" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/> 
<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

using copyField it store value of latlong

```
<copyField source="latlong"  dest="location"/>
```

Query:

```
  d=5&fq={!geofilt sfield=location}&pt=22.303894,70.802162&q=*:*
```

Response:

```
 {
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":1,
        "params":{
          "q":"*:*",
          "d":"5",
          "pt":"22.303894,70.802162",
          "fq":"{!geofilt sfield=store}",
          "_":"1557114448320"}},
      "response":{"numFound":15,"start":0,"docs":[
          {
            "zipCode":"360003",
            "currencySign":"₹",
            "suspendedByAdmin":false,
            "likeCount":45,
            "id":509,
            "longitude":70.8147741,
            "latlong":"22.3024966,70.8147741",
            "_version_":1632752689826758656,
            "store":"22.3024966,70.8147741},
         {...
```